# AndroidManifest is missing although it exists

Tags: java, android, compilation, compiler-errors

I compile my android application

everything pass OK

but when I try to debug my application on the mobile device (using eclipse) I get an error:

`AndroidManifest is missing`

this is strange as the file exist, and complication passes

[image]

Comment: Clean the project and again run it

Comment: Try: Click on your project -> Refresh (F5) -> Go to "Project" in the menu bar -> Clean (and clean the project). If all else fails, restart eclipse. Let me know what happens next

Comment: @Tamanna - the ultimate solutions to all Android related errors in eclipse... Clean and/or Restart.. :P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For all developers who face this problem :

```
 1. Click on your project -> Refresh (F5) 
 2. Go to "Project" in the menu bar -> Clean (and clean the project)
 3. If all else fails, restart eclipse
```